# Time efficiency of Power operation?

Tags: performance, optimization, language-agnostic, mathematical-optimization, processing-efficiency

I was just wondering about power operations and their time efficiency. Since a power operation is effectively:

```
x^n = x*x*x...[n times]
```

Does that mean calculation of x^n takes approximately O(n) time (assuming that multiplication is O(1), which I'm not sure it is)? Or do modern programming languages/hardware architecture have optimizations that reduce that to O(1) or something similar? If there are optimizations that exist, please explain (or post a link to an explanation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an optimization based on [successive squaring](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SuccessiveSquareMethod.html) that allows you to compute powers in a logarithmic number of multiplications.  For example, instead of computing b<sup>8</sup> as b*b*b*b*b*b*b*b, you can compute

b<sup>2</sup> = b * b
b<sup>4</sup> = b<sup>2</sup> * b<sup>2</sup>
b<sup>8</sup> = b<sup>4</sup> * b<sup>4</sup>

See [SICP 1.2.4 Exponentiation](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.4) for more details.  I also have a post on my blog that shows a [fast exponentiation](http://www.billthelizard.blogspot.com/2010/01/sicp-exercise-116-fast-exponentiation.html) implementation in Scheme.